# Ampscript getting error

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, html

I'm getting below error while working on ampscript, tried to de-bug it, but  not sure what I'm doing wrong

```
There is an error in your email. Please contact your customer service representative. 
Error 1: Script SET Statement Invalid<br>An error occurred when attempting to resolve a script expression. See inner exception for detail. 
Script Expression: CONCAT('<tr style="border:1px solid #000001;"><td align="center" valign="top" style="',@styletd,'">',FormatDate(DateAdd(Now(1), -1, "D"), "DD-MM-YYYY"),'</td>','<td align="center" valign="top" style="',@styletd,'">',@TotalCount4000,'</td>','<td align="center" valign="top" style="',@styletd,'">',@TotalCountmin4000,'</td>,'<td align="center" valign="top" style="',@styletd,'">',@Resultperday,'</td></tr>')
 MemberID: 510003833 JobID: 0 Invalid characters appear at the end of the parameter value Function Call: 
CONCAT('<tr style="border:1px solid #000001;"><td align="center" valign="top" style="',@styletd,'">',FormatDate(DateAdd(Now(1), -1, "D"), "DD-MM-YYYY"),'</td>','<td align="center" valign="top" style="',@styletd,'">',@TotalCount4000,'</td>','<td align="center" valign="top" style="',@styletd,'">',@TotalCountmin4000,'</td>,'<td align="center" valign="top" style="',@styletd,'">',@Resultperday,'</td></tr>') Parameter Value: </td>, Invalid Character: < <br>Invalid Content: <br>set @result = CONCAT('',FormatDate(DateAdd(Now(1), -1, "D"), "DD-MM-YYYY"),'','',@TotalCount4000,'','',@TotalCountmin4000,','',@Resultperday,' ')
```

Below is the code part where I'm getting error.

```
set @result = CONCAT(
'<tr style="border:1px solid #000001;"><td align="center" valign="top" style="'
,@styletd
,'">'
,FormatDate(DateAdd(Now(1), -1, "D"), "DD-MM-YYYY")
,'</td>'
,'<td align="center" valign="top" style="'
,@styletd
,'">'
,@TotalCount4000
,'</td>'
,'<td align="center" valign="top" style="'
,@styletd
,'">'
,@TotalCountmin4000
,'</td>
,'<td align="center" valign="top" style="'
,@styletd,'">'
,@Resultperday,
'</td></tr>')
```

Comment: it appears this section is missing an '  ,'</td>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have missed a single quote near the end, right after this part - `@TotalCountmin4000,'</td>` ,so it should be `@TotalCountmin4000,'</td>',`.

As a recommendation to prevent such issues in the future, you can use [Visual Studio Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/) + [AMPscipt extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=sergey-agadzhanov.AMPscript) to highlight the code (could be done with different tools as well) and check your code there. If something is wrong, in most cases, you would notice it quickly since it is going to be highlighted differently -
[image]

Comment: Thank you EazyE and Niko for the help, it solved my issue - my brain is totally freezed :D

Comment: @darkCloud, happens with everybody from time to time. I have added one small tip to my answer to prevent future occurrences of the same issues :)